# More complex file extension on windows using two extension approach?

Tags: windows, file-extension

On Windows, I can have an app associated with *.txt file. So all *.txt open in AkelPad (notepad replacement).

However, this editor is great but does not support international characters well.  (special signs in Czech language)

Is there a workaround where I could have *.txt files open on AkelPad and *.cz.txt open in PSPad?

Comment: AFAIK, no. You could always do a right-click and Open With.

Comment: Your best solution would to have a intermediate program detect the second extension. Why not change the extension of Czech documents to .cztxt?

Comment: Why not change the extension order to *.txt.cz? That way you can configure PSPad to open *.cz files.

Comment: txt.cz solution is OK but not perfect because the OS will not think of it as text files and index it and I would prefer it it would stay as a "traditional" txt file (only a subtype of it). I want the same with .xml and .ODM.xml and have an ODM editor and a generic xml editor. (and not do everthing twice for .txt and .cz